# phonegap and geolocation service not working on device

Tags: cordova

I was working with phonegap by a couple weeks but when I got to geolocation service found problems. In browser is working fine but compiled doesn't (using build.honegap.com).

In my config.xml file I have something like this:

```xml
Config package name, id, author, icon,etc...

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

and an androidmanifest.xml only with this:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.me"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="6.5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
</manifest>
```

Just for testing, I did this script (jquery), but is just working on chrome browser. Always is fired the error function (always enters the if sentence, "Nav on"):

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) { 
        alert('Nav on');
        setTimeout(function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            alert("success " + position.coords.latitude + ' , ' + position.coords.longitude)
        }, function(error){
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        },
        {enableHighAccuracy:true});
        }, 600);
    }else{
        alert('Nav off');
    }
};
```

Some idea what's wrong with my code? I have been working all weekend about this and nothing

P.S, I have a samsung galaxy s2 for testing and  sorry about my english.

I forget to say that the error message say:

> code: 2
>   message: Failed to start Geolocation service

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that your code is bug free  ! 
If you are sure then you need to do one more thing ! 
Just change the security settings of your Android device.
Go to Settings -> Security -> Check the "Unknown sources" checkbox
in order to allow your apk to be run without any problem.

Hope it works as it did for me!

Best,

Answer (score -1):

On some Android devices

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

won't return the geolocation, unless you set the enableHighAccuracy option to true. Replace the call to navigator.geolocation with this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{enableHighAccuracy: true});
```